# Android Wear - access mobile shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, wear-os

I'm using SharedPreferences on my mobile app to save data 
(e.g. for creating a recycler view list from that data)

Now I added a wear module and I'm trying to get the same list on my wear device. Is it able to access the shared preferences on my mobile from my wear device?

If your answer is no, what is the best alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider the wearable module as a separate application.

The wearable application is not capable of reading the SharedPreferences of your mobile application.

If you want to share data between your mobile and wearable applications you need to sync the data with [Data Layer Api](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/data-items.html).

Hope it will help!

Comment: I don't think I agree with the statement, "You should consider the wearable module as a separate application". You can share code easily between mobile and wear modules by having a "common" module. And as a user, I would expect certain settings to be set only once on my mobile device and the settings persist over to the wearable. For instance, if I'm in the U.S. and I want to see data in imperial format vs. metric, then if I set this as a setting in the mobile app, I should not have to set the same setting in the wear app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't access mobile Shared Preference, but you can send data using data map or message api, and you can use gson library to send custom objects as string